# Reduce time for automating the installation and configuration of ubuntu vm

Tags: performance, shell, ubuntu, sparse-file

Could anyone please let me know how to reduce the time to create a vm with installation and configuration of around 1000 packages.

I am using shell scripts to automate and basic version of ubuntu server edition . Is there any techniques to increase the performance?

I have identified one alternative. Like building a local repository in the base ubuntu server. So that the installation will reduce time. But the major disadvantage is that the size of the base image is getting increased if we add local repository.

Is there any techniques to reduce size after adding local repo. Like freeing up sparse files etc...? and if yes, how it can be done.

And is there any other techniques which increases performance?

Comment: Do you know what is taking all the time? Have you timed the process? Without that it is virtually impossible to comment.

Comment: Yes, there might be basic things which needed to be taken care right? So I thought I will get info on that

Comment: Avoid downloading more data than you need. Avoiding doing more work than you need. Avoid spawning more processes than you need. etc. But none of those are at all meaningful or helpful without more information and context. For all we know you could have a `sleep 1h` in a script somewhere or be downloading your packages from half-way around the world, twice.

Comment: I got it, let me go through and provide more inputs here. Thank you Etan